# Why does java.util.Properties extend Hashtable<Object, Object> instead of Hashtable<String, String>?

Tags: java, generics, properties, hashtable

As the title states: I'd like to find an answer to the question why [`java.util.Properties`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Properties.java) extends `Hashtable<Object, Object>` instead of `Hashtable<String, String>`?

```
class Properties extends Hashtable<Object,Object> { ... }
```

I wonder because the method [`setProperty(String key, String value)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Properties.java#Properties.setProperty%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29) accepts only String values and the properties are based on the String key-value representation. The full method body is on the link above and here:

```
public synchronized Object setProperty(String key, String value) {
    return put(key, value);
}
```

The same goes for the [`getProperty(String key)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Properties.java#Properties.getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) method and the other ones.

Is there any specific reason extend `Hashtable<Object, Object>` and use Strings? Is there any use-case I should be aware while using `Hastable<Object, Object>` or `HashMap<Object, Object>` like in this way?

Comment: Agreed, thank you for the link. I was searching for an answer with `Hashtable` key an not `Map`. It gave me wrong results. Thanks :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s one reason: The class predates generics.

`Since:
JDK1.0`

The team updating the Java libraries for generics had to balance “now we can accurately capture semantics” and “people will have a lot a broken code”.  Most of the time, the libraries were updated to compile and run with existing code, at some cost in specificity.

Comment: It makes sense, thank you! :)